# Sqlite Error: Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to update the database in my sqlite but it's giving the error:

> Error: Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean

Here are my codes:

```
public boolean updateEntry(long _rowIndex, String entryName, double entryTel, double entrySellp, int entryQty, String entrydate, int entryStaff, Context c)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ENTRY_NAME, entryName);
        values.put(ENTRY_TEL, entryTel);
        values.put(ENTRY_SELLINGPRICE, entrySellp);
        values.put(ENTRY_QTYSOLD, entryQty);
        values.put(ENTRY_DATESOLD, entrydate);
        values.put(ENTRY_STAFFDISCOUNT, entryStaff);


        // updating row
        return _db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, KEY_ID + " = " + _rowIndex , null);
    }
```

The return statement is underlined in red. What is the problem with my statement? I've rechecked many times but can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return _db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, KEY_ID + " = " + _rowIndex , null);
```

`db.update()` method returns int value, use below code:

```
int returnValue= _db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, KEY_ID + " = " + _rowIndex , null);
return returnValue==1 ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

the `update()` method doesn't return `boolean` it return an integer presenting the updated rows, so change the return type of your `updateEntry` with int